# Paytm in localhost sandbox environment gives something went wrong error

Tags: php, payment-gateway, sandbox, paytm

I am using sandbox test credentials in localhost. I have downloaded paytm kit from github.

When i checkout and redirect to paytm site, I am getting an error like this:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can drop an email at : payments.onboarding@paytm.com

Answer (score 0):

You might be passing the wrong value of MID please check once ,
extra space after MID is also not considered .

Pass the extra parameter CALLBACK_URL to get the response along with all parameters that you are using

If you are using a framework 
try 
this staging server URL.
define(‘PAYTM_TXN_URL’, ‘https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction’);